# Refactoring and mocking to support unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, refactoring, moq

I am trying to write unit test for a huge project where testability has never been though of when coding. I've started mocking objects and writing tests, but I realize I have to refactor a lot of our code in order to be able to mock it.

This is one of the methods I want to create a test for:

```
public List<DctmViewDefinition> GetDctmViewDefinitions()
{
    List<DctmViewDefinition> dctmViewDefinitions = new List<DctmViewDefinition>();
    DataPackage dataPackage = MyDfsUtil.GetObjectsWithContent();
    foreach (DataObject dataObject in dataPackage.DataObjects)
    {
        DctmViewDefinition view = GetDctmViewDefinitionFromXmlFile(dataObject);
        dctmViewDefinitions.Add(view);
    }
    return dctmViewDefinitions;
}
```

The MyDfsUtil-class handles webservice-calls and I want to mock it. 
MyDfsUtil is divided into 14 partial classes each consisting of 300-500 lines of code. So there is a lot of code!

This is an extract of the class to give you the idea:

```
public partial class MyDfsUtil
{
    public string Locale { get; set; }
    public string DfsServiceUrl { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public DataPackage GetObjectsWithContent()
    {
        //Some code here
    }
```

}

I am using Moq and therefore I can't mock this class directly (as far as I know). I have to either create an interface, an abstract class or make the methods virtual.
So, what I was have been trying to find out is: What is the best approach in order to be able to mock MyDfsUtil?

First, I was thinking to create an interface, but what about the variables (Locale, UserName etc.) used all over the code?

Secondly, I tried to create an abstract base class MyDfsUtilBase with all the variables and made the methods in the base class returning NotImplementedException. Like this:

```
public abstract class MyDfsUtilBase
{
    public string Locale { get; set; }
    public string DfsServiceUrl { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public void GetObjectsWithContent()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then Resharper tells me to add the 'new' keyword to the my GetObjectsWithContent()-implementation in the MyDfsUtil-class. Or I can declare my methods in the base class as virtual and then user the 'override'-keyword on the implementation. But if I have to declare my methods virtual anyway, I can just do that in MyDfsUtil and then I do not need to create an abstract base class.
I have been reading about virtual methods, and it seems like people don't agree on whether to use them or not. Using virtual methods in MyDfsUtil will make my refactoring-assignment easier and it makes me able to mock them. Is there any best practice for cases like mine?

I'm trying to do this the best, simplest way. I have no experience unit-testing or mocking and I really want to do this without introducing too much complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First, I was thinking to create an interface, but what about the
>   variables (Locale, UserName etc.) used all over the code?

You can include properties in interfaces.

> Is there any best practice for cases like mine?

I would recommend you to use [Interface Segregation Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/interface-segregation-principle.html) and create bunch of small interfaces  which would be implemented by your `MyDfsUtil` class:

```
public interface IDfsService
{
    string Locale { get; set; }
    string DfsServiceUrl { get; set; }
    string UserName { get; set; }
}

public interface IDataPackageService : IDfsService
{
    DataPackage GetObjectsWithContent()
}

public interface IFooService : IDfsService
{
    Foo GetFoo();
    void DoSomethingWithFoo();
}
```

Make `MyDfsUtil` implement these small interfaces

```
public partial class MyDfsUtil : IDataPackageService, IFooService
{
    public string Locale { get; set; }
    public string DfsServiceUrl { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public DataPackage GetObjectsWithContent()
    {
        //Some code here
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then make other classes depend on small interfaces instead of usage this huge class. E.g. your class can depend only on `IDataPackageService`.

Benefits:

- You don't need to refactor your monster class now. From clients point of view it will look like already refactored. Later you can split into small classes with base class and do other refactorings.
- You don't need to deal with all members of your monster class. If you are testing client which uses only methods A, B and C, then invert dependency between client and `MyDfsUtil` by introducing small and simple interface. Easy to mock, easy to understand.
- It's like outside-in development - after writing tests for clients you will have set of interfaces which clients need (btw you will be surprised - it can happen that some or even many of `MyDfsUtil` methods are not used by any client). Further refactoring of `MyDfsUtil` will be much easier, because you will not think how to group its functionality into smaller classes - that will be already defined by interfaces.

Comment: So I guess you didn't like the approach with declaring all methods I want to test virtual?

Comment: @amgravem exactly - it's better to depend on abstraction (and interface is the perfect type of abstraction). Its easily mocked. It does not require any efforts on MyDfsUtil modification (well, you just  need to list interfaces which it implements)

Comment: Yes, this will definitively make our code more manageable. It has grown to become a monster throughout the years. Feels good to fix it!

Comment: @amgravem thanks, Btw I have added one more important benefit of this approach

Comment: @BinaryWorrier yep, I had similar issues too :) Ah, legacy code... who did write it all?

Comment: Eh . . . in my case I wrote quite a lot of it. You come back to it 5 years later and what made perfect sense then, now not so much! :p

Answer (score 1):

I was exactly where you are three or more years ago.

My advice to you would be to leave `MyDfsUtil` alone, don't touch it.
(I assume it's a static class with static methods?)

Instead create an interface and matching class (say `ISaneMyDfsUtil` & `SaneMyDfsUtil`)

Starting off with that one method you give as an example `GetDctmViewDefinitions` add to the new class and interface the `MyDfsUtil` method that it uses `GetObjectsWithContent`. This "new" method on the new class simply delegates directly to the existing - and untestable `MyDfsUtil` class. You inject an instance of this class into the class under test.

There are multiple reasons to do it this way.

Making `MyDfsUtil` mockable *probably* isn't ideal.

1. The class is probably used at various levels of code through out the project. Testing a single method will soon require you to mock - in detail - several of it's methods.
2. The class is **way to big** and needs to be re-factored into different classes with single responsibilities. You can do that by rolling different interfaces and classes that sit over `MyDfsUtil`. In time - when you have time - functionality can come out of `MyDfsUtil` and into the new classes where it actually belongs.
3. The methods in `MyDfsUtil` probably return too much for your use cases. e.g. say the metod you're testing needs a list of Customer Ids from `MyDfsUtil`. You call `MyDfsUtil.QueryCustomers(myOrderId);` which returns a list of customers. You've code that does stuff **and only ever uses the Id properties of the customers**. When mocking that call you have to create customer objects, set the ids, and pass back the list of customers. In the `SaneMyDfsUtil` you can have a `QueryCustomerIds` method that **only** returns the customer ids. It make the Code Under Test more explicit, and makes mocking for the tests simpler.

I had some legacy software here that used a static Dal object with hundreds (if not thousands) of methods. I wrote some code that automatically generated **Sane_Object** classes and interfaces for it. As efforts go to introducing seams for testing it wasn't **awful** but I learned in time it was far from ideal, and following the pattern I've laid out here would have saved time and effort and would have helped me push Unit Testing to the team in an easier manner.

I could now answer [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317217/singletons-to-facilate-unit-tests-in-a-legacy-code-base-a-good-idea-or-not) and say, no it's not a good idea.

A final word read [The Art of Unit Testing](http://www.manning.com/osherove2/%5D%28http://www.manning.com/osherove2/) before you do too much else (honestly buy it and read it from cover to cover)
Then keep [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) on your desk, dip in and out of it and keep it as a reference for when things get tough.

Any questions just shout

Comment: It's good to know that it's not only me struggling with this stuff. I can see the resemblance with your case 3 years ago. I am afraid someone will be mad when I tell them what I've done (afterwards, of course). As to your question, it is actually not a static class. I think it will be interesting finding out really how much clutter that exists inside this class. Thanks for the reading suggestions, will definitively buy the books (and read them as well)!